# How to upgrade XBMC Live via command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, kodi

I've been unable to do a fresh install of XBMC Live 9.11 to my hard drive.  Everytime it fails at the Install System step.  But I am able to get XBMC Live 9.04.1 to install successfully.

How do I upgrade XBMC Live 9.04.1 to 9.11?

I understand that Ctrl+Alt+F2 brings up the command line, but what are the next set of commands to run?

Comment: Are you using XBMC Repack : https://sourceforge.net/projects/xbmc/files/

Comment: Yes, the repack and it still keeps failing.  So that's why I'm looking for a command line solution.  I've tried different hard drives and burning different Dvds with similar results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XBMC Live is Ubuntu based, so either of [these](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Lucid#Upgrading_Jaunty_or_Karmic_to_Lucid) should work (the first method is the recommended one):

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I'll try this on my XBMC system when I get home to verify.

Comment: I'll give this a try when I get home too.  :)

Comment: @sunpech Did it work?  I got home and realized I already had 9.11 on my system, so couldn't try the upgrade.  The names "9.04.11" and "9.11" seem to imply they are dates which are lagging the Ubuntu releases (Ubuntu every year has a .4 in april and a .10 in october, so Ubuntu 10.4 was released a few months back, so XBMC might have a version based off that... Which means I may want to upgrade soon).

Comment: @Dan I keep forgetting to try it.  Hopefully tonight or tomorrow I will try it.

Comment: Ran the first set of methods.  It seems to have upgraded to 9.10, but upon reboot it only gives me the XBMCLive login prompt.  I can't seem to get xbmc to graphically autostart.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the right answer, because it does upgrade it.  I'm just having trouble getting the UI to start up.

Comment: Try to upgrade XBMC manually using `sudo apt-get install xbmc` since when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade` it usually keeps xbmc the same version.

Comment: You should backup everything in /home/, that way if you are forced to do a re-install, you can than replace the new /home/ with your old /home/ which will restore all of your configuration.  You may not even noticed that there was a re-install done.

Comment: Once you have /home backed up, it may be worth a shot to remove all the files in your main user (probably xbmc) so remove all the files from /home/xbmc and then try starting it up.  This will check if it might be one of your personal settings that is stopping it from booting.  If that doesn't work you can restore it from your backup.